# Scala map over a Future

Tags: scala, future

In the following example, what is the expected behaviour?

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
val someFuture = Future { 1+1 }.map(elem => {
  println("mapping immediately")
  elem.toString
})

someFuture.onComplete {
  case scala.util.Success(value) => println(s"Got the callback = $value")
  case Failure(e) => e.printStackTrace()
}
```

Is the following output always guaranteed?

```
mapping immediately
Got the callback = 2
```

Comment: Yes, that's the whole point of map to chain things and give you a new future where the computations are chained.

Comment: If you are asking whether the mapping function is always executed before the result of the mapping function is given to the onComplete handler, then yes.

Comment: Cool! That was what I was expecting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends.

```
val someFuture = Future { 1+1 }.map(elem => {
  println("mapping immediately")
  elem.toString
})
```

`someFuture` will be executed eagerly and the `println` will be executed.

```
someFuture.onComplete {
    case scala.util.Success(value) => println(s"Got the callback = $value")
    case Failure(e) => e.printStackTrace()
}
```

`onComplete` is an event listener for a `Future`. This is called only when this **future is completed, either through an exception, or a value**, to apply the provided function.

Therefore, it will always execute after the execution of the `someFuture`.

Assuming that the `someFuture` is not going to fail, the order

```
`mapping immediately
 Got the callback = 2`
```

is guaranteed.

For what ever reason, if there's an exception thrown, then the result would change. In that case `Got the callback = 2` will **not** be printed and `mapping immediately` may or may not be printed.

Hope this helps.